# Sentry Python stack trace showing built-in rows from logging

Tags: python, django, sentry

When I use Sentry with LoggingIntegration to capture logging events (`log.error` etc.) am I supposed to see the Python logging built-in lines in the stack trace (for example the highlighted line  894 in `__init__.py` as seen in the attached image)? Or is this due to some misconfiguration?

Is it possible to the show only the lines starting from where `log.warning` is used (in this case, `xxx/apiclient.py` line 52)? For me, the built-in stack trace is just noise.

[image: Sentry event]

Comment: It's not possible. You can to show full stacktrace or none.

Comment: Ok. If this is the final answer then I can at least stop trying to work my way around it.

Comment: Please refer to https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-python/issues/692